# Force table update for Kohana (even if nothing to save)

Tags: mysql, timestamp, kohana

1. I have `TIMESTAMP` field in database which updates with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when table is updated.
2. I have a form which may be updated with no changes.

Problem is that I need to update `TIMESTAMP` every time the form is submitted, even if no information was changed or added.

Now my code looks like `$current->values($_POST)->save();`

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. I've edited your post to remove the greetings as is SO you will say "thank you" principally by voting once you will have answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$current->values($_POST)->save()` code doesn't update table data because no changes was made with loaded Model (Kohana tracks it).

To update DB data on every submit use something like:

```
$post = Arr::extract($_POST, array('title', 'text')); // array of POST fields you want to extract from POST
$post['TIMESTAMP'] = time(); // Always set new timestamp

$current->values($post)->save();
```